# JSON success is not triggering

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am having trouble with my JSON payload.  The success function does not fire.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.
JLS

I get the value in the console so I know the query works okay but it is not in a key/value pair it just echos "VALUE" and does not triggers success.

```
//JS file ***UPDATED***

    $(document).ready(function(){
// code to get all records from table via select box
        $("#school").change(function() {
            var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            var dataString = 'school='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'cif_submit.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

```
//Here is the php  ***UPDATED***

if($_REQUEST['school']) {

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT streetname FROM schoolinfo WHERE fullschoolname = :schoolname");
$stmt->execute (array(':schoolname' =>$_REQUEST['school']));

while($mydata = $stmt->fetch()) {   

    echo json_encode($mydata);  
} }
}

The JSON RESPONSE is:
{"streetname":"Colbeck Road, PO Bag 7200","0":"Colbeck Road, PO Bag 7200"}
```

Comment: What do you get with alert(schooldata)?? basically what is the php returning? and what id are you passing to it?

Comment: I am getting the same result with data and schooldata console responded with 
{"streetname":"1st Street N.E","0":"1st Street N.E"}

Comment: but the alert(schooldata) does not trigger

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused by this response.  Are you saying I need to change the sql response variable to some other than data and it will affect my AJAX success response?  I am getting a properly formatted JSON response in the console.  Can you send a sample of what you mean?

Comment: I mean browser console... I have updated my code and included the response

Comment: Besides the extra `}` just below the `json_encode` call, everything looks fine. Maybe there's some garbage in the output and jQuery is choking converting or the status code is wrong. Try `die();` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the schooldata to data will fix the issue.

Comment: bcz I do not see schooldata defined anywhere and you are making the Key/value pair in dataString and passing it to data, hence data should have what you are expecting.  Try passing data to success function and alert data to see what you get.

Comment: It seem data and schooldata both send the same response:  {"streetname":"1st Street N.E","0":"1st Street N.E"} but the success function still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `change()` event gets called when you unfocus the input.
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Tried with this code and worked perfectly.

JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="school" type="text">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
// code to get all records from table via select box
        $("#school").change(function() {
            var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            var dataString = 'school='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'a.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(schooldata) {
                    if(schooldata) {
                        alert('success');
//$("#streetname").text(schooldata.streetname);  TRIED THIS NO JOY
//$("#streetname").hide(); TRIED THIS NO JOY
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
if($_REQUEST['school']) {
    $datas = array();
    $datas[] = array('streetname' => 'test');
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $data = $data['streetname'];
        //$streetname = trim(json_encode($data), '"');
        //echo json_encode($data);
        echo json_encode($data, true);
    }
}
```

[image: Alert]

Comment: Thanks you the sample code but when I copy these two script verbatim my payload in now:

'test'); foreach ($datas as $data) { $data = $data['streetname']; //$streetname = trim(json_encode($data), '"'); //echo json_encode($data); echo json_encode($data, true); } } ?>